# How to fix get_report error in tubern package in R?

Tags: r, google-api, youtube-analytics-api

I'm trying to use the get_report() function from the 'tubern' package, but got an error message.

```
library(tubern)

yt_oauth("XXX", "XXX",token = "")

report <- get_report(ids = "channel==UCiMg06DjcUk5FRiM3g5sqoQ", metrics = "views", start_date = "2020-09-01", end_date ="2020-09-01")

#>Error in tubern_GET("reports", querylist, ...) : Not Found (HTTP 404).
```

Would anyone happen to know what could be behind the error? Could it possibly have something to do with my yt_oauth?

Comment: is this YouTube or YouTube analytics?

Comment: @DalmTo YouTube analytics

Comment: You will have much better luck with getting an answer if you tag your questions properly then.   Welcome to stack.